# What do we do when we cannot post code due to licensing issues?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, licensing

I have been facing some problems with my production code and I've been trying my best to give all the info I can in my SO posts. The only problem is that I am not allowed to post my code on any forum, except in case they are personal projects; questions to which I post from my other account here on SO (nope, no sock-puppeting). How do I ask for help in such cases?

Comment: Most of the time, you shouldn't post "your" code anyway but a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Is that not possible in your cases?

Comment: Take the time to create a MRE instead; hopefully when you actually try to do so, you'll actually find the problem and fix it yourself too.

Comment: nope, That'll still mean posting some code, right? I mean, won't it functionally still be the same?

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you forbidden from posting code because it belongs to your company, or literally code written by you? Where does the licensing issue come from exactly?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, the former... it belongs to my company.

Comment: Then writing your own MRE should be fine, no? It's unlikely that we can help with internal/proprietary tasks, so you would have to extract the generic parts.

Comment: If your business is so against you talking to others (outside of the business) on problems then the end result is that if you don't know how to do something, you don't know how to do it. If, after performing a large amount of research, you still don't, then the answer to your employer is "I do not have the knowledge/skills to implement this." if that's a problem for you, and  your employer, then both you and them need to sit down to discuss how you can either recruit someone who has the skills, help develop your skills, or allow you the speak to others with some kind of MRE.

Comment: @Larnu, I spoke to my manager about this. What he said is at the most, the company can arrange a hands-on training session with either a well-known trainer or the company that created the technology (this has been done twice in the past, not for me though; I am new to the job) with the latter being the most probable.

Comment: At least you have a solution in place then, and your business is happy to provide training where skill sets are missing; some are not so lucky.

Answer (score 18):

> I mean, won't it functionally still be the same?

It'd still function the same, but it wouldn't be *their* code.

If, for example, you're having trouble getting a button's text to change for a government agency web site, you could say your existing HTML looks like this:

```html
<input id="btn1" class="btn" type="button" value="Dummy Text" />
```

instead of

```html
<input id="obvious-gov-id" class="obvious-gov-class-name" type="button" value="Validate Permit" />
```

It's their code that's licensed, not the entire concept of an input button.

Comment: This is dubious from the perspective of copyright law (starting with something copyright, then modifying it, then claiming that the new result is free of copyright is...really complicated). For non-trivial examples, it also presumes a fairly high level of understanding of what is and isn't germane to the issue at hand, and runs the risk of creating distracting bugs.

Comment: @justanotherguy Given that this is a work imposed requirement of not posting code, I *strongly* recommend discussing the issue with your manager and getting buy-in from them prior to posting anything. IMO, doing what's above, particularly if done on company time (which it should be, as you're trying to solve your company's issue) *doesn't* remove any requirement which your company may have, unless the company says it does (or unless the specifics of the legal agreement indicate that it does, which I consider *very* unlikely).

Comment: @Makyen true but still on the border. They might be able to patent the idea/function or even the program (see: [linux vs unix litigations](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2332329/insurance-group--linux-free-of-copyright-violations.html)), but how can they patent a `switch` statement?

Comment: Anyways, I took your advice and discussed the issue with my manager. I am not allowed to do anything which might reveal the functionality they are trying to build. So doing what is suggested in this answer is probably out the window anyway.

Comment: @justanotherguy I'm glad to hear you talked with your manager. It doesn't really matter what they can patent or copyright (two very distinct things). What matters is what they could get pissed-off about and fire you for. Generally, when employed by a company, they own your work output, under most conditions, and get to say what's done with it. If their desire for privacy makes it take longer for you to solve a problem, or even makes it *impossible* for you to solve a problem, that's a *business* decision for the company to make, not one for an individual contributor to unilaterally decide.

Comment: @Makyen, on a not entirely unrelated note, what does a downvote on a meta question like this signify? Like on a feature-request, it means people do not want the feature or on a new announcement, it means they haven't liked it but on a question requesting help, what does the DV signify (apart from the obvious "does not show effort" text shown in the hover, that is)

Comment: @justanotherguy Voting on Meta sites is different than on main sites. On Meta sites, votes much more strongly represent people's agreement or disagreement with the position expressed in the post, rather than just an expression of people's opinion on the quality of the post, although they can also reflect that. On bug reports, voting can represent people being able to reproduce the issue, or not. As a consequence, downvotes on Meta shouldn't automatically be considered to mean there are problems with the post. On the other hand, it doesn't hurt to double-check that the post quality is good.

Comment: @justanotherguy For *this* question, I'd guess the downvotes represent people's frustration with trying to answer questions which don't provide enough information (e.g. don't provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging questions). That happens a *lot*, so there's quite a bit of frustration built up for those trying to answer.

Comment: @Makyen *votes much more strongly represent people's agreement or disagreement with the position expressed in the post* thanks a lot for the clarification :) but I haven't expressed any position, not to mention that I don't feel the post quality can be improved. I have been posting here (from my personal account) for quite a while now... Anyways, thanks again for the advice :)

Comment: Probably from people doing the "Duh! A good MRE will look nothing like the original code!" and they're right, but making an optimal MRE means you know what the bug is, just don't know how t fix it. Normally that's not the case when asking a question, which means you need to make the MRE by brute force, isolating the bug by trial and error and a bit of good ol' common sense. It's really hard work, and usually it results in no question asked at all. Because you found and fixed the sucker.

Comment: @user4581301 *"It's really hard work, and usually it results in no question asked at all. Because you found and fixed the sucker."* - that is the dream, it is that hard work bit which is kind of expected of you before you can write a good question. I wonder how that would affect the number of questions asked daily. Drop it by 50%? More?

Comment: I've been trying to ask a good question on Stack Overflow for years. Every time I think I've got a good one, I start dotting the is and crossing the ts and find the damn answer or a work-around. [Well, there's always tomorrow.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZqVUjziexk)